# Что делать когда сайт под атакой?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Логи из production.log такого плана :

```
Started GET "/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v4.2.0"
Started GET "/?yclid=18656461618948913218"
Started GET "fontawesome-webfont.eot"
Started GET "//mysqladmin/scripts/setup.php"
```

и т.д

Подскажите пожалуйста что делать?  Все возможные уязвимости я вроде бы исправил, по крайней мере которые выдавал гем brakeman

Как остановить атаку? Ну, и по возможности напишите названия гемов для тестирования защиты от взлома. Спасибо

Comment: а что вы хотите получить? какой результат?

Comment: опишите какой ответ вы ожидаете? вы хотите остановить атаку? проверить сайт на уязвимости?

Comment: Судя по запросам, это не направленная атака, а общий скан на уязвимости в популярных движках/CMS или других продуктах. Скорее всего, скан не зайдёт дальше [не-]обнаружения PHP-продуктов. Обновлённый по третьей цифре Rails должен быть неуязвим по уже известным проблемам безопасности, остаются уязвимости в вашем собственном коде, автоматически выявить которые практически невозможно.

Comment: @АлександрТарасович пожалуйста, не указывайте фреймворк в заголовке вопроса - для это есть метки

Comment: @АлександрТарасович добавьте эту информацию в ваш вопрос

Comment: @MikhailVaysman [спорно](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/607/181100). Вопрос в первую очередь определяется заголовком, и потому ключевые технологии держать в заголовке допускается.

Comment: *Как остановить атаку?* -- выключить сайт. До тех пор, пока на сайт есть доступ у посетителей, будет возможность "обстреливания" его на предмет уязвимостей, даже если уязвимостей нет. Автоматика уязвимости находит плохо, даже brakeman находит весьма ограниченный круг уязвимостей, и только на основе статического анализа кода.

Comment: @D-side Я вас понял, логично, не поспоришь.

Comment: @D-side в данном случае вопрос не очень связан ключевой технологией. если бы сайт был на python, то вы бы дали аналогичный совет по атаке.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman и именно это и есть суть "ответа": **никаких особенных мер именно для Ruby on Rails нет**. Собственно, поэтому это и комментарии :)

Comment: Ничего делать не нужно, такие логи это норма, если сервер отвечает на них ошибкой 404